# How to fetch the text from span tag?

Tags: automated-testing, xpath

I need to fetch text 'Finance' from the span tag below to compare that with another value which is saved in a file.But I am not able to fetch that.

```
<span class="panel-text col-md-8">Finance</span>
```

Here is the full code for the above

```
<div class="dashboard-panel dashboard-type-employee-input">
    <div class="dashboard-panel-header">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
        <span class="dashboard-panel-title">Provided Employee Input</span>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard-panel-content">

        <!---->
        <div class="ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
                <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">Department in which the employee works:</span>
                <span class="panel-text col-md-8">Finance</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
                <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">Employee's Date of Birth:</span>
                <span class="panel-text col-md-8">03-08-1990</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
                <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">County in which the employee works:</span>
                <span class="panel-text col-md-8">Iowa</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
                <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">Employee's home address:</span>
                <span class="panel-text col-md-8">Station Street</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
                <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">Employee ID:</span>
                <span class="panel-text col-md-8">M1669</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->
            <!---->
            <div class="col-md-12 ng-star-inserted">
                <span class="panel-text label col-md-4">Authorization Code:</span>
                <span class="panel-text col-md-8">45637</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The xpath selector for the above code is given below

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@id="employer-call"]/div[2]/div[2]/efx-tabs/div/efx-tab[4]/div/div/employee-input-panel/efx-dashboard-panel/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]'));
```

How can I get the text from the tag.I tried by adding text() to the path and also using getText() and InnerHtml

Comment: Try `//*/span[contains(text(),"Finance")]`

Comment: OP needs to get the text from en element. If they know the text to use in "contains" they would not need to fetch it.

Comment: @AlexeyR.How to use contains to check if it is present in span tag?Like if Finance is stored in a variable

Comment: @RRR This is actually how to check if tag contains "Finance". But if you have "Finance" value to put to "contains" function, that does not make sense to fetch the text from span later since you already had "Finance" text which would be returned by getText method

Comment: @AlexeyR.I need to fetch the text in span tag and need to compare that with data I entered from a variable(deptData).So can we use contains method to check if span tag contains the data in the variable deptData

Comment: @RRR you can get the text and just compare it using the programming language you are using. "contains" method would also be an option but if you use contains you just get true or false as the result. If you use getText you can output the actual content against the expected one.

Comment: @AlexeyR.It would be great if that can be done with contains to check if the span tag contains 'Finance' which is deptData variable.Can you help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75980/discussion-between-rrr-and-alexey-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution by refering to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478905/protractor-element-gettext-returns-an-object-and-not-string

I used

```
expect(this.deptData.getText()).to.eventually.equal(employee.department);
```

to fetch the data from span tag and compare that with the data in employee.department

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the text "Department" is only used once inside the element with id of "employer-call" I would do this:

- get the employer-call element: `employer = element(by.id("employer-call"));`
- get the element within the employer-call element that contains the text "Department": `sibling = employer.FindElement(by.xpath())` and use `span[contains(text(), "Department"]`
- from that element, depending on the language you are using and the methods you have available you can either get the next sibling node, or get the parent div then the second span in the div. If you can get the next sibling, that's easier, but if not, getting the parent then the other child and retrieving its text will give you the value you want to check.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `first-child` to get first div element or `:nth-child(1)`.

```
   WebElement myElement1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dashboard-panel-content div:first-child .col-md-8"));
   System.out.println(myElement1.getText()); //Should print out "Finance"
```

to get second element `div:nth-child(2)`

```
   WebElement myElement2 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dashboard-panel-content div:nth-child(2) .col-md-8"));
   System.out.println(myElement2.getText()); //Should print out "03-08-1990"
```

Answer (score 0):

The html code you have provided is not completely relevant to your xpath. Assuming there is really the element with `id="employer-call"` try the following:

```
//*[@id="employer-call"]//div[@class="dashboard-panel-content"]/div[1]/div/span[2]
```

Comment: It is giving back a large junk of data

Comment: This is likely because there are multiple "dashboard-panel-content" under your "employer-call". Try //*[@id="employer-call"]//div[@class="dashboard-panel-content"][NUM]/div[1]/div/span[2] where NUM = the index of particular item. Or provide either the complete HTML in your question or the link to the source.